# docker exec and running state

Tags: docker, shell, unix, process, docker-exec

I built an image, say `my_dbt_image`, with a custom install of a program, say `dbt`. I also wrote a little binary `my_dbt` like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# define flags, e.g. '--workdir=/vol' '--volume $PWD:/vol'
docker run --rm $flags my_dbt_image dbt $@
```

so that when a user enters `my_dbt <args>` in their terminal, the script actually runs `dbt <args>` inside the container. Hope this makes sense.

Seems to work fine, maybe a bit slow. I figure that to speed things up, instead of running a new container every time the user enters a new command, I should reuse the same container, leveraging `docker exec`.

Currently, after the command is run, the container goes in stopped state (status `exited`). This makes sense. I'm a bit confused about the logic of `docker exec`. Why does the container need to be running in order to throw a new command at it?

In my situation, do you think I should:

- stop the container after each user command is executed, and (re)start it when a new user command is entered, or
- keep the container running?

Any comments or advice on my approach are welcome.

Comment: A container is a wrapper around a single process; when that process exits the container ends.  It's not like a VM where the container has an independent long-running identity and you can launch new services inside it.  For this setup, `docker run --rm` seems like a better match, or better, run the program outside a container directly on the host.

Comment: Have you run benchmarks to see how much time you would save?